# What happens when Annihilation is played in combat on a monster that is not the last played card?

Tags: munchkin

In *Munchkin*, what is the effect of Annihilation card when played in combat with multiple monsters, targeting a monster that is not the last played card? Will its power still count for combat resolution?

[image: annihilation: play this card at any time to permanently remove any one card from the game. it does not go to the discard pile... put it back in the box and forget it. the target card must be in play when you use Annihilation on it. if an opponent had *just* played it, it is canceled and has no effect.]

P.S. is there a centralised resource with card explanations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you target any monster in a multi monster combat situation that monster will be removed from the game. Since it was removed from the game it will no longer have any impact on the combat that is taking place.